# Editing simpleform locales to enable custom error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form within my app that I build using simple_form.  What I am trying to do is edit my error messages to something a little different than the default.  I am working on my `simple_form.en.yml` file and I think that may be where my problems are happening.

With what I have, i'm not sure I understand what exactly goes in the settings file, and I am hoping someone can go over what I have and advise me on where to go.

My model is like so (this is my entire model)

```
class FormSubmission < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :email_sales

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :organization, :email, :phone, :recognition, :inquiry, presence: true

  private

  def email_sales
    FormSubmissionMailer.update_sales(self).deliver_now
  end
end
```

Here is one of the areas of my view

```
= simple_form_for @form_submission do |f|

  .fieldSet.span8
    .field.reco
      = f.input :first_name, input_html: { class: "formStyling" }, label: "First name", required: false
```

Finally, in my `simple_form.en.yml` file I have this here

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        formsubmission:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "cannot be empty"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple_form does nothing special for validation error messages I18n and leaves all work to the default Rails I18n processing. The `simple_form.en.yml` localization file only deals with the various options to *display the form* and its elements (labels, hints, etc., see the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n)) and has nothing to do with error messages.

So, if you need to set the *error messages* localization, have a look at the [official Rails guide on I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) instead. Actually, I think that your `simple_form.en.yml` example might work, if you moved the error message localizations to the default Rails locale file for English: `config/locales/en.yml`.

Comment: That is quite helpful @BoraMa, thank you very much for the advice, the rails docs were useful enough for me to get things figured out!